# Linq to XML Nested tags join issue

Tags: c#, silverlight, linq, silverlight-3.0, linq-to-xml

I have an XML that looks like this

```
<Labs>
  <Lab id="a" name="a">
    <Test name="aa"></Test>
    <Test name="ab"></Test>
    <Test name="ac"></Test>
  </Lab>
  <Lab id="b" name="b">
    <Test name="ba"></Test>
    <Test name="bb"></Test>
  </Lab>
</Labs>
```

I want to get the data from this XML in a single table using LINQ to XML through a single select statement. If you could provide me with a reference of how to do the query.

I am binding the Linq to XML query output to silverlight grid. The output should be like this in silverlight...

```
LabName    TestName
a          aa
a          ab
a          ac
b          ba
b          bb
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Maybe you could provide an output sample.

Comment: Updated the code segment above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK here is a working example:

```
string xml =@"<Labs>
  <Lab id='a'>
    <Test name='aa'></Test>
    <Test name='ab'></Test>
    <Test name='ac'></Test>
  </Lab>
  <Lab id='b'>
    <Test name='ba'></Test>
    <Test name='bb'></Test>
  </Lab>
</Labs>";

XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(xml);
IEnumerable<XElement> xElements = document.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name == "Test");
var results =  xElements.Select(m => new
                                        {
                                            Test = m.Attributes("name").FirstOrDefault().Value, 
                                                    Lab =m.Parent.Attributes("id").FirstOrDefault().Value
                                        });
        foreach (var result in results)
{
            Console.Write(result.Lab);
            Console.Write('\t');
            Console.WriteLine(result.Test);
}
```

Comment: @Shahid Did it help? Did you try it??

Answer (score 0):

for a lambda free version of the above solution posted by `Aliostad`. You can use this as well...

```
        var Tests = from tests in doc.Descendants("Test")
                    where tests.Attributes().Count() > 0
                    select new LabTestModel
                                {
                                    LabName = tests.Parent.Attribute("Name").Value,
                                    TestName = tests.Attribute("Name").Value
                                };
```